# Python 3 invalid syntax in list comprehension

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm working with a large file of data on a sporting event, and I want to see how often each team comes up in the data. I want to end up with a list of tuples containing a team number and a count of their frequency. I have written the following code to do so:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fo = open("Data.txt", "r")
content = [x[:-2] for x in fo.readlines()]
data = []
for i in range(1, len(content)):
    data.append(content[i].split(","))

teamList = []
for l in data:
    print(l)
    teamList.append((l[1],1)) if not len[item for item in teamList if l[1] in item] > 0 else teamList = map(lambda a : (l[1], a[1]+1) if l[1] in a else a, teamList)
print(teamList)
```

When I run the code, I get told that the for in the second to last line is incorrect syntax. How can I fix this error?

Comment: `len[...` is not valid Python syntax. What are you trying to do there? Also, the way you're trying to append will only work if you have an `if` and `else` statement in that line (think ternary operator).

Comment: Neither is `else teamList = map(` (assignment is not possible mid-expression). I suggest to completely rewrite that line of code, aiming for readability.

Comment: I was trying to tell if the team was already added to the list by checking the length of the collection of instances of that team. I'll change that, thank you!

Comment: `teamList.append((l[1],1)) if not len[item for item in teamList if l[1] in item] > 0 else teamList = map(lambda a : (l[1], a[1]+1) if l[1] in a else a, teamList)`

Whoa! This is definately not the way python code should be written like. Read about what `len` does and how to format python code according to PEP-8.

Comment: @not_a_robot Strictly speaking, the syntax is fine, it's just guaranteed not to do anything useful when executed.

Comment: @mwchase I suppose it depends on your definition of "fine" ;) ... Try running `len[0]`... You will get a `TypeError`. I suppose if you reassigned something to `len` (i.e. overwrote the built-in namespace), like this `len = [0,1,2]`, then `len[0]` would be valid syntax.

Comment: @mwchase, well, you're correct, `len[something]` would just result in `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable` exception in attempt to take an index/slice from a `len` function. But, yeah, that syntax is technically correct (in a sense it's valid Python expression).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count team mentions, use `collections.Counter`.

If `l` is an iterable where team name is the first element (and you don't care about the rest), it should be as simple as `collections.Counter(item[1] for item in data)`.

If you do care about the rest (`l[2]` etc in terms of your code), it could be something in lines of:

```
teams = collections.defaultdict({"seen": 0})
for item in data:
    name = item[1]
    seen = teams[name]["seen"]
    teams[name]["seen"] += 1
    if seen < 1:
        teams[name]["something_else"] = item[2]
```

And if you don't need the counts, the usual tool for "had I seen that already" is `set` data type. Just a basic `set(l[1] for l in data)` should do the trick.

Comment: This is definitely better than my answer. Deleted it and upvoted you.